# Program not replacing letters

Tags: java

I am currently learning how to use Array lists in Java and i am stuck on a simple but annoying problem..

```
import java.util.*;

public class ReplacingALetter
{   
 public static void main (String[] args)
 {
    String word = "Banana";

    List underscore = new ArrayList(word.length());

    int i;
    for (i=0; i<word.length(); i++)
    {
        underscore.add(i, "x"); 

    }

    System.out.print(underscore);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Enter a letter: ");

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    String letter = sc.nextLine();

    if (sc.equals("B"))
      {
        underscore.set(word.indexOf("B"),"B");
      }

    System.out.print(underscore);

 }   
}
```

For some reason it is not substituting the first x in the array 'underscore' with the letter B :/

The Output of that code is [ x x x x x x ]

But when i enter this code:

```
    import java.util.*;

public class ReplacingALetter
{   
 public static void main (String[] args)
 {
    String word = "Banana";

    List underscore = new ArrayList(word.length());

    int i;
    for (i=0; i<word.length(); i++)
    {
        underscore.add(i, "x"); 

    }

    System.out.print(underscore);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Switching First x with B: ");


    underscore.set(word.indexOf("B"),"B");


    System.out.print(underscore);

 }   
}
```

It works Perfectly and the output is [ B x x x x x ]

Can't figure out what i'm doing wrong....

Comment: Did you step through the program in debugger?

Comment: `if (sc.equals("B"))` --> `sc` is a `Scanner`, `"B"` a string, they will never be equal...

Comment: @jlordo.. Why afraid of posting that as an answer. That makes a perfect one.

Comment: @user1985021 you can accept an answer which will tell the answerer you found the answer correct and helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The only difference I spotted in your 2 examples is, that one uses a if condition:

```
if (sc.equals("B")) {
    underscore.set(word.indexOf("B"),"B");
}
```

whereas the other one executes

```
    underscore.set(word.indexOf("B"),"B");
```

unconditionally. Your `sc` is a `java.util.Scanner`, `"B"` is a string. They can't be equal, so the method is never called in your first example.

Answer (score 1):

`if (sc.equals("B"))` this condition is always `false` because `sc` is not an object of class `String`.

You should change your code to:

```
if (letter.equals("B")) {
    underscore.set(word.indexOf("B"),"B");
}
```

Comment: hmmmmmm i see... so what could i do to change the x ?? If u noticed im trying to create a sort of hangman but first i got to get the simple stuff to work :P

Comment: You should replace the condition to `letter.equals("B")` as I posted after edit :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (letter.equals("B"))
      {
        underscore.set(word.indexOf("B"),"B");
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to check if letter is equal to B not sc is equal to B.

```
String letter = sc.nextLine();    
    if (letter.equals("B"))
      {
        underscore.set(word.indexOf("B"),"B");
      }
```

Comment: ohhhhhh god i didn't even realise such an innocent mistake -.- thanks guys :D

Comment: @user1985021 you are welcome,... please accept anyone of the answers here if  you are happy with em.. and good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Modify this snippet

```
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    String letter = sc.nextLine();

    if (sc.equals("B"))
      {
        underscore.set(word.indexOf("B"),"B");
      }
```

to

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

String letter = sc.nextLine();

if (letter.equals("B"))
  {
    underscore.set(word.indexOf("B"),"B");
  }
```

In the former you are comparing Scanner object with the string "B" which will never be equal.
In the latter it compares the string read from standard input to "B".